# Repeatable steps in a Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a groovy script that calls other jobs to stop and start tasks. (see below). I would like to re-use the code inside the `steps {` over and over again. Can I do this without having to repeat the code?

Basically I want to have the next stage for another API that I can start or stop, then another, etc. These are then built with parameters on the Jenkins where radio buttons decide whether to stop or start.

```groovy
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
  environment {
    containerInstanceIdsToStartOn = "463b8b6f-9388-4fbd-8257-b056e28c0a43"
    region = "eu-west-1"
    cluster = "mis-core-dev"
  }
  agent any

  stages {

    stage('Authentication API (dev)') {
      environment {
        apiName = "authentication_API"
        taskDefinitionFamily = "mis-core-dev-authentication-api"
        taskDefinition = "mis-core-dev-authentication-api"
      }
      steps {
        script {
            if (params."${apiName}".contains('Stop Task')) {
            build(job: 'Stop ECS Task (utility)',
            parameters: [
            string(name: 'region', value: params."${region}"),
            string(name: 'cluster', value: params."${cluster}"),
            string(name: 'family', value: params."${taskDefinitionFamily}")
            ])
          }
            else if (params."${apiName}".contains('Start Task')) {
            build(job: 'Start ECS Task (utility)',
            parameters: [
            string(name: 'region', value: params."${region}"),
            string(name: 'cluster', value: params."${cluster}"),
            string(name: 'taskDefinition', value: params."${taskDefinition}"),
            string(name: 'containerInstanceIds', value: params."${containerInstanceIdsToStartOn}")
            ])
          }
            else if (params."${apiName}" == null || params."${apiName}" == "") {
            echo "Did you forget to check a box?"
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

  post {
    always {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248224/how-do-i-run-the-same-stages-on-multiple-nodes-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline/56249918

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to share parts of a declarative pipeline. The declarative pipeline DSL is processed in a special way at runtime where you can't split out some of the pieces. You could share some logic in how some of the blocks are executed (like the code used inside of a `script` block), but the sharing capabilities are limited to basically the entire pipeline definition itself

From the [*Shared Library* documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines):

> Only entire pipelines can be defined in shared libraries as of this time. This can only be done in `vars/*.groovy`, and only in a `call` method. Only one Declarative Pipeline can be executed in a single build, and if you attempt to execute a second one, your build will fail as a result.